# I want to remove duplicated entries in a data.frame based on one column

Tags: r

```
uniqueIDs <- data.frame(unique(MASTERFILE$Number), MASTERFILE[,3])
```

So I have this big table called "MASTERFILE". In this table, I have a column called "Number" which has a number for each row. Some of the rows will have the same number, so for instance:

1

2

3

3

4

5

So what I would like to do, is to remove the duplicate "3" entry. However, I also want column number 3 to be included in my new "uniqueIDs" data frame (hence the `MASTERFILE[,3]` part).

Unfortunately, when I try to run this, it will say that the rows from the unique function are different from the rows in column 3, which is obvious, however the question now is, how can I make sure those same rows that where removed in the unique function, also get removed in the 3rd column?

Comment: Maybe `MASTERFILE[!duplicated(MASTERFILE$Number), c("Number", "Col3")]`?

Comment: Hey Frank! Thank you very much, that worked smoothly!

Comment: Maybe put that in an answer and then accept it. It works because `duplicated` returns a logical vector of the same length as its argument, and is therefore a valid index vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this questions has already been asked and answered, but something like this should work:

```
MASTERFILE[!duplicated(MASTERFILE$Number), c("Number", "Col3")]
```

Comment: You don't need `"Number"` in order for it to work. The key to @Frank 's solution is that the row index vector is valid.  You might also want to attribute that to the comment you took it from.